# css of selects and buttons not same line

Tags: jquery-mobile

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbxDC.png

as you can see labels of selects and buttons not same line.

Which css i overload or change ?

Comment: The text is _center_ aligned. Each text has different length, obviously they won't be aligned.

Comment: @Omar, i think the OP means that buttons with no icon, left icon, right icon, and selects all put the center at slightly different positions: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/C4GLZ/

Comment: @ezanker true, I didn't notice the icons. When it comes to CSS, I take my hat off to you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The icons at left and right of the buttons/selects are causing the center alignment to use a different center.  You can solve this with some CSS:

```
.ui-btn-inner{
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
.ui-select .ui-btn-icon-right .ui-btn-inner{
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;   
}
```

> Without the CSS: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/C4GLZ/)
>
> With the CSS: **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/C4GLZ/1/)**

Depending on the exact elements and icon-positions you are using, you may need some more CSS to equalize padding on each side of the centered text.

Comment: Prefect answer as always!